# display database data in webgrid in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Asp.net mvc 4 project.list.cshtml file is:

```
columns:grid.Columns(
grid.Column(header:"Serial No",format:<div>@(item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item))</div>),
grid.Column(ColumnName:"UserName",header:"UserName"),
grid.Column("ColumnName:"FullName",header:"FullName"),
grid.Column(header:"Email",format:<a href ="mailto:@item.EmailID"@item.EmailID></a>),
grid.Column(header:"Is Active?", format:<input type="checkbox" checked="@(item.isActive)"/>)
```

it showing following exception:

> 1.CS0103: The name 'item' does not exist in the current context
>   2."<" is not valid at the start of a code block. Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

I have changed the validation to *html5*

Comment: start the format with @. example: @<div>@(item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item))</div>

Comment: Did you do it for all the tags in the grid.column?